# Gradle build task failing with java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file

Tags: java, gradle, log4j, build.gradle

I have a java project that uses gradle for dependency management. The first time when i build the project using my build.gradle script with "gradle installApp" command it successfully creates the jar file for the project and the jar runs perfectly fine using java -jar command.

Log4j is being used as the logging utility and it generates the log file as per the log4j.properties when i execute the jar using java -jar command.

The problem that i am facing is that when i try to re-build the project without stopping the jar, my build fails with the following exception

```
D:\MyProject\backend\mymodule\MyModuleJAR>gradle installApp --stacktrace
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar
:installApp FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':installApp'.
> java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: D:\MyProject\backend\mymodule\MyModuleJAR\build\install\MyModuleJAR\log\my.log

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':installApp'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: D:\MyProject\backend\mymodule\MyModuleJAR\build\install\MyModuleJAR\log\my.log
        at org.gradle.util.GFileUtils.deleteDirectory(GFileUtils.java:142)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.SyncCopyActionDecorator$SyncCopyActionDecoratorFileVisitor.maybeDelete(SyncCopyActionDecorator.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.SyncCopyActionDecorator$SyncCopyActionDecoratorFileVisitor.visitDir(SyncCopyActionDecorator.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker$1.postVisitDirectory(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker$1.postVisitDirectory(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker.walkDir(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:143)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visitFrom(DirectoryFileTree.java:127)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visit(DirectoryFileTree.java:117)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.SyncCopyActionDecorator.execute(SyncCopyActionDecorator.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.execute(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.execute(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyActionExecuter.execute(CopyActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.AbstractCopyTask.copy(AbstractCopyTask.java:83)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:227)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: D:\MyProject\backend\mymodule\MyModuleJAR\build\install\MyModuleJAR\log\my.log
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:1390)
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1044)
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:977)
        at org.gradle.util.GFileUtils.deleteDirectory(GFileUtils.java:140)
        ... 78 more


BUILD FAILED
```

Below is my build.gradle script

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

eclipse {
    project {
        name = 'MyModuleJAR'
    }
}

repositories {

    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.1'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.5'
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.7'
}

def jarName = "${project.name}.jar"

def jarCopySpec = copySpec {

    def cfg = new Properties()
    cfg.put('jarname', jarName.toString())

    from(file("src/main/resources")) {
        include '*.properties'
    }

    from(file("src/dist")) {
        include 'deploy/*.xml'
    }

    from(jar) {
        rename jarName, "${cfg.jarname}"
    }

    into("lib") {
        from(configurations.runtime)
    }
}

jar () {

    manifest {
        def manifestClasspath = configurations.runtime.collect { "lib/" + it.getName() }.join(' ')
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'mymodule',
                'Built-Date': new Date(),
                'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version'),
                'Main-Class': 'org.module.main.MyMainClass',
                'Class-Path': manifestClasspath
    }
}

task installApp(type: Sync) {
    description 'Installs MyModule application'
    into { file("${project.buildDir}/install/${project.name}") }
    with jarCopySpec
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:all" << "-Xlint:-processing" << "-Xlint:-serial" << "-Werror"
}
```

And my log4j.properties file has below configuration

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console, RollingAppender

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.immediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.console.encoding=UTF-8  
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern=[%p] %d [ %C{1} : %M : %L ] - %m%n%throwable{n}

#log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR, RollingAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=./log/myLog.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='_'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d [ %C{1} : %M : %L ] - %m%n%throwable{n}
```

The log4j.properties file is stored at below path

```
src/main/resources/log4j.properties
```

The jar is generated at the following path

```
D:\MyProject\backend\mymodule\MyModuleJAR\build\install\MyModuleJAR\myModuleJAR.jar
```

And the log is generated at the below mentioned path

```
D:\MyProject\backend\mymodule\MyModuleJAR\build\install\MyModuleJAR\log\myLog.log
```

What i am aiming to achive is that

1. My "gradle installApp" build command should be able to overwrite the
   existing project jar with new code changes without me requiring
   explicit shutting down of the jar in order to re-build it.
2. My log file should not be deleted by the gradle build at every fresh
       build. Rather it should be append the log statements generated by
       the new build to the already existing log file.